# How to turn off auto-tagging/numbering in bookdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown, bookdown

I would like to manually number equations in a bookdown project. However, bookdown seems to auto number equations according to the chapter. Is there a way to turn this option off?

Here is an example equation in the second chapter:

```
$$
\begin{aligned} 
y = 2x 
\end{aligned}(\#eq:1) \tag{1}
$$
```

then, the rendered output produces

```
\begin{aligned} 
y = 2x 
\end{aligned}\tag{1}\tag{2.1}
```

Comment: I haven't used Bookdown, but I'd guess using `\begin{align*} ... \end{align*}` (without the `$$`) should get you what you want.

Comment: Unfortunately, that does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `{equation*}`.

Compare:

```
---
title: "Numbering"
header-includes: \usepackage{amsmath}
output: 
  pdf_document:
  latex_engine: xelatex
--- 

\begin{equation}
y = mx+b
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\tag{}
y = mx+b
\end{equation}

\begin{equation*}
y = mx+b
\end{equation*}

$$
\begin{aligned} 
y = mx+b
\end{aligned}(\#eq:1) \tag{1}
$$
```

[image]